# What does 'static' do in Flow?

Tags: reactjs, static, flowtype

I've seen some example of using Flow in React, there's `static` syntax for defaultProps. As I know in all OOP `static` does mean a keyword to declare a member so that can be use without creating an instance of a class. Does it have the same meaning in Flow?

And why only defaultProps has to be declared as `static`? But the props and state don't have to.

[Flow docs](https://flow.org/en/docs/frameworks/react/)

Comment: That has nothing to do with `flow`. It's syntax of the programming language. `static` means it is shared by all instances of the class, it doesn't depend on an instance. It's not only `defaultProp`. It's also `propTypes`, `contextTypes` etc. All configuration shared by all instances of a component.

Answer (score 0):

The keyword `static` belongs to JavaScript. It defines a `static` property as in available on the class rather that instances created with the class. Example:

```
class A {
  static myStatic = 1;

  static foo() {
    ...
  }
}

const a = new A();
A.myStatic // 1
A.foo // function
a.myStatic // undefined
a.foo // undefined
```

Nota that static class properties are still in proposal stage. You can already use Flow to give those values type though.